# App Insights responds with, "HTTP/1.1 206 Telemetry sampled out."

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, appinsights

In Fiddler I can see my exception being sent to App Insights. App Insights responds with, "HTTP/1.1 206 Telemetry sampled out."

I do not see this error logged previously, or at all, in App Insights. Can someone help me understand why I am seeing the 206 response? Have too many other exceptions been logged to App Insights, so it is sampling this one out?

My iKey looks correct.

**Steps to Reproduce**
Call appInsights.trackException explicitly.
appInsights.trackException(t);

- OS/Browser: Google
  Version 92.0.4515.159 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Windows 10

- SDK Version [e.g. 22]: ai.0.js
- How you initialized the SDK: App Insights is declare inline in aspx page.

  var appInsights = window.appInsights || function (a) { function b(a) { c[a] = function () { var b = arguments; c.queue.push(function () { c[a].apply(c, b) }) } } var c = { config: a }, d = document, e = window; setTimeout(function () { var b = d.createElement("script"); b.src = a.url || "xyz.../ai.0.js"...

**Expected behavior**
Exception should show in App Insights.

**Additional context**
Exception does not show in App Insights

I am using an old version of the SDK. But hoping that someone can explain the 206 response from App Insights.

HTTP/1.1 206 Telemetry sampled out.
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
x-ms-session-id: ...
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Name, Content-Type, Accept, Sdk-Context
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Mon, 23 Aug 2021 13:33:56 GMT
Content-Length: 287

{"itemsReceived":3,"itemsAccepted":0,"errors":[{"index":0,"statusCode":206,"message":"Telemetry sampled out."},{"index":1,"statusCode":206,"message":"Telemetry sampled out."},{"index":2,"statusCode":206,"message":"Telemetry sampled out."}],"appId":"xyz..."}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I do not see this error logged previously

[Sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling) not an error. It is turned on by default in many scenarios. For javascript you can configure sampling as outlined [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#configuring-fixed-rate-sampling-for-web-pages-with-javascript)

It could also be that you hit [the daily data cap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/pricing#manage-your-maximum-daily-data-volume):

> When you create an Application Insights resource in the Azure portal, the daily cap is set to 100 GB/day. When you create an Application Insights resource in Visual Studio, the default is small (only 32.3 MB/day).

I suspect it is the latter, as when sampling is turned on using the sdk you wouldn't see it cross the wire. Please see [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#ingestion-sampling) describing how to adjust the cap.

Answer (score 1):

How I resolved my issue:
Open your Application Insights in Azure. Go to "Usage and estimated costs". Click "Data sampling". Then set "All data (100%)". Click "Ok" to apply.